Diacritic-insensitive sorting with polars in python
My background is closer to linguistics than programming-
is a way to make .sort() insensitive to diacritcs (accent marks such as á or ô). Currently when I sort I get "aeiou" before "áéíóú" when I want "[aá][eé][ií][oó][uú]" or "aáeéiíoóuú". This, though I doubt it's relevant to this question, is my code (the locale thing was an attempt to fix this suggested by google's gemini):
import os
import locale
import polars as pl

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')  # set the locale to en_US.UTF-8

# print the current working directory
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

# Make paths for the lexicon and the sorted lexicon
LexiconPath = r'C:\Users\mawan\Documents\Code\WorldBuildingCode\KalagyonManNyal_Lexicon.csv'
UnsortedLexiconPath = r'C:\Users\mawan\Documents\Code\WorldBuildingCode\KalagyonManNyal_Lexicon_Sorted.csv'

# read the csv file name KalagyonManNyal_Lexicon and make it a DataFrame
df = pl.read_csv(LexiconPath)

df.fill_null("-")  # fill null values with a dash
# print the first 5 rows of the DataFrame
print(df)

# sort the DataFrame by the column "Lexeme" in alphabetical order

df_sorted = df.sort("Lexeme")

print(df_sorted)

write_csv = df_sorted.write_csv(UnsortedLexiconPath, include_bom=True)  # write the sorted DataFrame to a new csv file

# print(df.filter(df.is_duplicated())) # print duplicated rows
# print(df.columns)

# make a dataframe that filters by the part of speech input by the user

PoS = input("Enter the part of speech you want to filter by: ")

df_PoS = df.filter(df['PoS'] == PoS)
print(df_PoS)

So what I am looking for is either diacritic-insensitive sorting or custom sorting instructions so I can make some diacritics count as separate letter while others don't.
I tried using locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') after gemini, the generative ai, suggested it, but it didn't seem to change anything.

en_US means American English - and American English doesn't use áéíóú so it may not sort them.

en_US.UTF-8 on platforms that use glibc or in Windows should be safe. On glibc based systems it uses the glibc ISO/IEC 14651 collation table and will support any Unicode character from the version the table matches.

The title is asking for a diacritic-insensitive sort. This would mean a and à would have equal collation weights, so in Python, since it uses a stable sort` the relative ordering of the two letters relative to each other is based on their position in the data. For locale based sorting. Some locales will treat them as different at a primary level, ie completely separate letters that sort based on different positions in alphabet. Others will use a secondary difference so they will be grouped together but will have a specific ordering relative to each other.

@mavmav0 generative AI is very bad at answering questions involving Python internationalisation issues. But then Python documentation on internationalisation is also poor.  Generally I have to spend a lot of time figuring out what Python does and how I need it to work with multilingual text.

First I thought that en_US can't work because it is American English which doesn't use chars áéíóú so it may not sort them. But I tested it with pl_PL.UTF-8 and Polish chars ąęść and it also doesn't work.
Finally in documentation for sorting - comparison functions I found method which works for me (even with en_US)
import locale
import functools

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

words = sorted(words, key=functools.cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)) 

It also sorts lower case and upper case chars in different way - a A b B instead of A B a b

EDIT:
And for pandas I found
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

df.sort_values(key=lambda col:col.map(locale.strxfrm))

because it needs function which (as you can read in doc for pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()):

it should be vectorized. It should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the input.

Maybe it will work also with polars.
It works also with standard sorted()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

words = sorted(words, key=locale.strxfrm)


Code used for tests. Last sorting gives expected result.
import locale
import functools

words = 'ą a b ć c d A B C'.split()

print('before setlocal (no key)  :', sorted(words))
print('before setlocal (with key):', sorted(words, key=functools.cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

print(' after setlocal (no key)  :', sorted(words))
print(' after setlocal (with key):', sorted(words, key=functools.cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)))

Result:
before setlocal (no key)  : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ą', 'ć']
before setlocal (with key): ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ą', 'ć']
 after setlocal (no key)  : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ą', 'ć']
 after setlocal (with key): ['a', 'A', 'ą', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'ć', 'd']

EDIT:
Code for pandas
import locale
import functools
import pandas as pd

words = 'ą a b ć c d A B C'.split()
df = pd.DataFrame(words, columns=['words'])

print(df.sort_values('words'))
print(df.sort_values('words', key=lambda col:col.map(locale.strxfrm)))

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

print(df.sort_values('words'))
print(df.sort_values('words', key=lambda col:col.map(locale.strxfrm)))


EDIT:
Code which doesn't use key= in sort() but it creates column with values locale.strxfrm() and use it to sort rows. And later drops this column. Maybe it will works with polars which don't have key in sort()
BTW: locale.strxfrm() creates strange strings - I see Chinese characters :) - but it works.
import locale
import functools
import pandas as pd

words = 'ą a b ć c d A B C'.split()
df = pd.DataFrame(words, columns=['words'])

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

df['xfrm'] = df['words'].apply(locale.strxfrm)
df = df.sort_values('xfrm')
#print(df)
df = df.drop('xfrm', axis=1)
print(df)


EDIT:
Useful information from @Andj comment:

Fortunately en_US.UTF-8 is a safe locale. For other locales order may be different across different operating systems. For instance fr_FR.UTF-8 will sort very differently on Alpine Linux and macOS compared to Debian and Windows. For pandas there are few ways of handling things depending on what you want to achieve. A while ago I through together some rough notes on different approaches I was using at the time: https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/notebooks%2Fsorting_pandas.ipynb


This is great, and I can in theory work with this, but it's not happy about me trying to use sorted() on a dataframe. Traceback (most recent call last):
    df_sorted = df.sort("Lexeme", key=functools.cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))  
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
TypeError: DataFrame.sort() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'```
Any way to easily resolve this before I start writing a lot more than I need to?
Thank you very much!

first would check documentation for sort() on polars - maybe it has other option - like cmp in sort() in other languages (like C/C++). I can't test polars because it doesn't work on my very old CPU.

@mavmav0 one idea: use locale.strxfrm() to create new column with values and sort using this column.

The documentation is brief, sadly.
edit:
The formatting of this comment got very messed up. Here is the link to the documentation I found. https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.sort.html
It does list 6 parameteres, but from what I understand they are not all that relevant.
Thanks for all the help!

so you can try to use locale.strxfrm() to create new column with values and sort using this column, and later delete this column. It works on pandas but column with values from strxfrm() looks strange - I see Chinese characters :) - but it works.

I do not really understand locale very much. I will read up on it tomorrow, and see if it might help! My only other idea is adding another value to the dataframe denoting the index at which there should be an accented vowel, substituting the accented vowel for the corresponding plain vowel, doing the .sort, then based on the accent value substitute back the accented vowel.
This seems like a lot of extra work, and it feels like there should be an easier, less "roundabout" way.
Thank you very much for all the help, I will come back to you with whether or not your idea worked!

it seems locale.strxfrm() do the same - it creates (strange) strings which can be compared to get correct order. In answer I added example for pandas which uses extra column - and it can sort without key.

Fortunately en_US.UTF-8 is a safe locale. For other locales order may be different across different operating systems. For instance fr_FR.UTF-8 will sort very differently on Alpine Linux and macOS compared to Debian and Windows.  For pandas there are few ways of handling things depending on what you want to achieve. A while ago I through together some rough notes on different approaches I was using at the time: https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/notebooks%2Fsorting_pandas.ipynb

@Andj thank you, I added your comment at the end of answer to make it more visible for other people.

re: testing polars - There is a polars-lts-cpu package for older CPUs which may work for your system.

@jqurious thank you, polars-lts-cpu works for me :)

As it stands, I don't think Polars has any native support for this type of thing.
Using your example:
df = pl.DataFrame({"Lexeme": list("áéíóúaeiou")}).with_row_index()

>>> df.sort("Lexeme")
shape: (10, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ index ┆ Lexeme │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ u32   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 5     ┆ a      │
│ 6     ┆ e      │
│ 7     ┆ i      │
│ 8     ┆ o      │
│ 9     ┆ u      │
│ 0     ┆ á      │
│ 1     ┆ é      │
│ 2     ┆ í      │
│ 3     ┆ ó      │
│ 4     ┆ ú      │
└───────┴────────┘

As for replacing/substituting accents mentioned in the comments:
You could normalize the data: unicodedata.normalize()
And then remove the accents: .str.replace_all

(note: the Unicode Category syntax \p{CombiningChars} allows us to match them easily)

(
   df.with_columns(
      norm = pl.col("Lexeme").map_elements(lambda text: 
         unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text),
         return_dtype = pl.String
      )
   )
   .with_columns(
      key = pl.col("norm").str.replace_all(r"\p{CombiningMark}", "") # remove accents
   )
   .with_columns(
      pl.col("norm", "key").str.len_bytes().name.suffix("_len") # could be used for sorting ties
   )
   .sort("key")
)

shape: (10, 6)
┌───────┬────────┬──────┬─────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ index ┆ Lexeme ┆ norm ┆ key ┆ norm_len ┆ key_len │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ u32      ┆ u32     │
╞═══════╪════════╪══════╪═════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ 0     ┆ á      ┆ á    ┆ a   ┆ 3        ┆ 1       │
│ 5     ┆ a      ┆ a    ┆ a   ┆ 1        ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ é      ┆ é    ┆ e   ┆ 3        ┆ 1       │
│ 6     ┆ e      ┆ e    ┆ e   ┆ 1        ┆ 1       │
│ 2     ┆ í      ┆ í    ┆ i   ┆ 3        ┆ 1       │
│ 7     ┆ i      ┆ i    ┆ i   ┆ 1        ┆ 1       │
│ 3     ┆ ó      ┆ ó    ┆ o   ┆ 3        ┆ 1       │
│ 8     ┆ o      ┆ o    ┆ o   ┆ 1        ┆ 1       │
│ 4     ┆ ú      ┆ ú    ┆ u   ┆ 3        ┆ 1       │
│ 9     ┆ u      ┆ u    ┆ u   ┆ 1        ┆ 1       │
└───────┴────────┴──────┴─────┴──────────┴─────────┘

I'm not sure if that answers your question exactly, but may be of use.

Sorting options in Polars is very limited. Most examples that I have seen involved adding a column and generating something that can be used for sorting.
Options include:

creating a column where diacritics (non-spacing marks) are removed and the text is lowercased, although for some languages casefolding, or compatibility decomposition would be useful. An existing answer points to part of this solution.

create a column based on sort keys, either using Python's locale module or PyICU, a wrapper for icu4c library. An answer shows aspects of this.


I'll explore the second option:
import locale
import icu
import polars as pl

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale.getRoot())

df = pl.DataFrame({"Lexeme": list("cCáéíóúaeiouçÇßÁÉÍÓÚAEIOU")}).with_row_index()

First I'll use the locale module. I have set the locale to an English locale. English uses the default sort, without tailoring.
The following code will create a new column based on locale specific collation weights for the target column, then sort on the new column, before dropping the column:
df = pl.DataFrame({"Lexeme": list("cCáéíóúaeiouçÇßÁÉÍÓÚAEIOU")}).with_row_index()
df1 = df.with_columns(
    df['Lexeme'].map_elements(locale.strxfrm, return_dtype=pl.String).alias('locale_key')
).sort('locale_key')
df1 = df1.drop('locale_key')
list(df1['Lexeme'])
# ['A', 'Á', 'Ç', 'E', 'É', 'I', 'Í', 'O', 'Ó', 'U', 'Ú', 
# 'a', 'á', 'ç', 'e', 'é', 'i', 'í', 'o', 'ó', 'u', 'ú', 'ß']

The upper and lowercase characters are segmented, rather than sorting together. We could improve the sort by lower-casing or case-folding each string before generating the collation weights.
df1v = df.with_columns(
    df['Lexeme'].map_elements(lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x.casefold()), return_dtype=pl.String).alias('locale_key')
).sort('locale_key')
df1v = df1v.drop('locale_key')
list(df1v['Lexeme'])
# ['a', 'A', 'á', 'Á', 'c', 'C', 'ç', 'Ç', 'e', 'E', 'é', 'É', 'i', 
# 'I', 'í', 'Í', 'o', 'O', 'ó', 'Ó', 'ß', 'u', 'U', 'ú', 'Ú']

This version of the sort is closer to what we need in the sort. We are using a lambda function lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x.casefold() where the string is modified, i.e. casefolded before getting the collation key. This allows us to fine tune aspects of the collation. In the string above, it allows us to sort ß as ss, and all the uppercase characters as their lowercase equivalents.
It is important to note that handling casing in this way is a case-insensitive sort, and the resultant ordering of upper and lowercasing is dependent on the order of the data in the dataframe.
For PyICU:
df2 = df.with_columns(
    df['Lexeme'].map_elements(collator.getSortKey, return_dtype=pl.Binary).alias('icu_key')
).sort('icu_key')
df2 = df2.drop('icu_key')
list(df2['Lexeme'])
# ['a', 'A', 'á', 'Á', 'c', 'C', 'ç', 'Ç', 'e', 'E', 'é', 'É', 'i', 
# 'I', 'í', 'Í', 'o', 'O', 'ó', 'Ó', 'ß', 'u', 'U', 'ú', 'Ú']

The PyICU collation handles the case distinctions, and ß within the collation, so additional modifications, as in previous example, aren't required.
A key difference between the collation keys in the locale module and PyICU is the Polars datatype. For the locale module, we are using String objects, while _PyICU+ returns Binary objects as a collation key.
Obviously, with locale or PyICU, you can choose any available locale to use. With PyICU it is possible to write your own collation rules and use icu.RuleBasedCollator.createInstance().
Obviously mapping a function requires a performance hit compared in using Polars functions. Unnortunately there aren't many options available when it comes to sorting natural language content in Polars.
Edit:
as indicated above the modified locale sort will have inconsistent results based on relative ordering of upper and lowercase characters. To control this better, it is possible to sort by teh enw column and the Lexeme column, and use the descending parameter to control relative order of upper and lower characters:
df2 = df.with_columns(
    df['Lexeme'].map_elements(lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x.casefold()), return_dtype=pl.String).alias('locale_key')
).sort(['locale_key', 'Lexeme'])
df2 = df2.drop('locale_key')
list(df2['Lexeme'])
# ['A', 'a', 'Á', 'á', 'C', 'c', 'Ç', 'ç', 'E', 'e', 'É', 'é', 
# 'I', 'i', 'Í', 'í', 'O', 'o', 'Ó', 'ó', 'ß', 'U', 'u', 'Ú', 'ú']

or
df2 = df.with_columns(
    df['Lexeme'].map_elements(lambda x: locale.strxfrm(x.casefold()), return_dtype=pl.String).alias('locale_key')
).sort('locale_key', 'Lexeme', descending=[False, True])
df2 = df2.drop('locale_key')
list(df2['Lexeme'])
# ['a', 'A', 'á', 'Á', 'c', 'C', 'ç', 'Ç', 'e', 'E', 'é', 'É',
# 'i', 'I', 'í', 'Í', 'o', 'O', 'ó', 'Ó', 'ß', 'u', 'U', 'ú', 'Ú']

